# Performance issues in Phonegap iOS game after Ads + Flurry integration

Tags: html, cordova, iad, mobclix

I am developing a game using PhoneGap iOS. I integrated Ads in it using Mobclix as well as iAds. Also I integrated Flurry in the game for analytics.

But after integrating Ads in the game I am facing some performance issues in the game on some devices. They are as follows :-

**Ipod touch** :- Slow response to touch events, Animations are too slow, Rendering has become slow.
**Iphone** :- Animations are slow but better than Ipod touch.

It works fine on **Ipad**.

I have used PhoneGap to port our HTML5 code on the devices.

I checked Removing the Ads and Flurry Code then game runs Fine. I also searched extensively for this problem, but couldn't find a suitable answer. Looking forward to getting some help, here.

Comment: I use iAds and admob and didn't notice performance issues

Comment: @jcesar I have a lot of CSS, Jquery animations as well as animations on Canvas on every interaction of the player with the game, which are working fine without Ads integration. Still not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: try to remove just flurry and test the app, then put flurry back, remove mobclix and test again to see wich one is causing it.

Comment: after removing mobclix it works fine. that means Mobclix integration is causing the issue. I also tried iAds , but still it is affecting the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed (from first hand experience) that the Flurry HTML5 SDK can slow your app down, massively. It communicates with the server by inserting `SCRIPT` tags into the `HEAD` section of the DOM, which has three drawbacks that I can see:

1. Some browsers (e.g. mobile Safari on iOS it seems) will wait for `HEAD` scripts to resolve before running any other scripts
2. If you make multiple Flurry calls, you'll soon reach the browser's [concurrency limit](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/) for multiple downloads from the same server, since each call creates a new `SCRIPT` tag.
3. The script tags are never removed, so the DOM keeps growing.

One solution is to try the native Flurry SDK for the phone(s) you are targeting, but that's not an option if you are supporting browser WebApps, and increases your development time & download size for native apps.

I find it pretty shocking that the Flurry HTML5 SDK is so inefficient. Back to Google Analytics I guess.